# Django signals not called when app is registered using package name but works with app config class

Tags: python, django

I was experiencing a problem where my signals were not getting called. I have an app called `users` and in it I have a model for Profile that extends the django User model and when a user object is saved, I need to create a corresponding profile for it for that I added a signals.py module in the users app, here's my signals file

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

And inside my settings.py INSTALLED_APPS I added my app like this

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # other apps
    'users',
]
```

And my users/apps.py looks like this

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'users'

    def ready(self):
        import users.signals
```

After registration, the user object was getting created but no corresponding profile. I even put some debug statements in the signal receivers just to confirm my receivers were not getting called and yes the receivers were never getting called.

I couldn't find a solution to this as all answers I found on SO showed similar configurations that worked. Out of curiosity I decided to register the users app using config class and not the module name and changed my settings INSTALLED_APP to look like this

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # other apps
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
]
```

After doing that everything was working. On registration a new user, a profile was been created from within my signal receiver.

Now I don't understand what difference doing that makes. Everything(migrations, templates, etc) else was working fine with the previous configuration. Why did I have to change it for my signal receivers to work?

Comment: Did you add `default_app_config = 'users.apps.UsersConfig'` in `users/__init__.py` ?

Comment: No, that file is blank.

Answer (score 2):

Prior to the Django 3.2 version, Django was only checking `default_app_config` in your applications `__init__.py` file to determine which application configuration class should be used by default when you've not provided it explicitly in your `INSTALLED_APPS`. If you didn't specify one there, it will create a new, blank one for you and use that.

On 3.2 release this has changed and now, if there is `AppConfig` class in your `apps.py` file with `default = True` set, this one will be used by default or if your application defines only one `AppConfig` in the `apps.py` file and it doesn't have the `default = True` specified, this one will be used.

You can read more about the new behavior in the [changelog](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/3.2/#automatic-appconfig-discovery) and for the previous behavior, you can check [docs of the 3.1 version](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/applications/#configuring-applications-ref)

To fix your problem, you can either define `default_app_config` in your application or upgrade the Django version to 3.2 (given you have only one `AppConfig` defined or you've marked one with `default = True`), whichever is more relevant to your case.

Comment: I don't think this answers my question. Firstly I'd like to state that my code is now working and I just want to understand why using 'users.apps.UsersConfig' worked but just 'users' didn't. Meanwhile using just 'users', everything else works like database migrations for the 'users' app are been picked up fine.

Comment: As I've stated above, if you won't specify `default_app_config` for Django prior to 3.2, Django will ignore your `AppConfig` class and create a temporary, empty one just to initialize your application. If you specify one, Django will use that instead. This behavior changed in 3.2 though.